# Asp .net core httpsys exception - Access Denied

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I'am having trouble to find the right permission to give to a domain service account to be able to run my api (as a Windows Service).

I'm propbably missing something, so any help would appreciated :)

I registered the proper url with netsh.
I can run the service with my user account (which is admin like).
I am able to run the service if I listen to http://localhost:28000/public/v1/ but not with port localhost:80 or anything else than localhost.
I added my service account in the Administrators group, same error.

I'm working on virtual machine running Windows Server 2016 Standard. A domain is configured and I am the only computer on the domain.

Thanks

Here is the full stack trace:

> info:
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
>         User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users_esbapi\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key
>   repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest. info:
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.HttpSysListener[0]
>         Start 
>   info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.HttpSysListener[0]
>         Listening on prefix: http://localhost:80/public/v1/ fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.HttpSysListener[0]
>         Start 
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.HttpSysException (0x80004005): Access is denied    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.UrlGroup.RegisterPrefix(String
>   uriPrefix, Int32 contextId)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.UrlPrefixCollection.RegisterAllPrefixes(UrlGroup
>   urlGroup)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.HttpSysListener.Start()
>
> Unhandled Exception:
>   **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.HttpSysException: Access is denied**
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.UrlGroup.RegisterPrefix(String
>   uriPrefix, Int32 contextId)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.UrlPrefixCollection.RegisterAllPrefixes(UrlGroup
>   urlGroup)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.HttpSysListener.Start()    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys.MessagePump.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1
>   application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.d__26.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.d__5.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host)
>   at EventsServiceHost.StartConsole() in EventsServiceHost.cs:line 22
>   at Program.Main(String[] args) in Program.cs:line 38

Answer (score 0):

Here is a reply in case someone else comes across the issue.

```
netsh http add urlacl url=https://DNSALIAS:PORT/ user=DOMAIN\SERVICEACCOUNT
```

This assumes:

- You have created a DNS entry pointing to the host where the service is running
- PORT has been bound to the host DNS entry
- Service account was created in AD

If the service is already bound to another port, you will need to first issue a delete command

```
netsh http delete urlacl url=https://DNSALIAS:PORT/
```

Also make sure your service account has permissions to write log files in the environment where this will be running.